# I grabbed and used wrong oil on my 2014 Chevy Silverado

Tags: chevrolet, oil, silverado

I put 0W30 in my 2014 Chevy Silverado instead of 0W20.  Do I need to change the oil right away or will that be fine ... I live in Massachusetts if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't damage anything, however, you're going to want to get it changed as soon as possible. The reason for this being, it has the propensity to mess with the variable valve timing aspect of your engine. The computer is expecting a certain weight of oil to be used and how it will behave. Thicker oil will run differently, which could cause it to throw a code. Since you have oil in your truck and it's (at least I take it it's running, lol), it shouldn't cause a big issue, because oil does what oil does (you know, lubricate, cool, etc.). You just need the required oil to ensure it will continue to do it.